# Sphinx не всегда использует ключевые слова

Tags: php, sphinx, sphinxsearch

Проблема как обычно, пример:

```
запрос     ключевое слово     кол. результатов
Испанский     испанск              27
Испански      испанск              24
Испанск       испанск              24
Испанс        испанс                6
Испан         испан                24
Испания       испан                 0
```

Конфиг:

```
...
morphology          = stem_enru
html_strip          = 1
mlock               = 0
min_word_len        = 1
expand_keywords     = 1
index_exact_words   = 1
min_infix_len       = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx использует поиск по словоформам, а не по подстрокам. Поэтому, он не будет искать "испанс", т.к. это не корректная часть слова, а обрезанная.

Comment: Вы не внимательно читали мой вопрос. Главная проблема, что "испан" - словоформа для двух слов: "Испания" и "Испан"
Но по запросу "Испания" сфинкс нечего не возвращает...

Comment: Может быть это потому, что в тексте используются прилагательные "испанский", а словарь не считает прилагательное аналогичным существительному "испания", которого в тексте, вероятно нет?

Comment: имеет право на жизнь. Но я не использую словарь, мой конфиг работает по морфологии - определяет корень слова и по нему ищет. morphology = stem_enru - алгоритм нахождения корня в слове.